# Convergence of This integral?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, factorial

***Note, This is a re-post. My last question was poorly worded and I do not think it will be seen well.***

How can you show the convergence of
$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\mathrm{d}x \over \left(x!\right)^{\,\epsilon}}\,,\
\forall\ \epsilon > 0\,}$ if it's at all possible.

My thoughts and attempt was to first replace $x!$ with $\Gamma(x+1)$, since $x!$ only maps naturals to naturals.
So,
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\mathrm{d}x \over \Gamma\left(x + 1\right)^{\,\epsilon}}
$$
And now attempt to do the comparrison test, say, $2^{x}$. I could not find a function that is everywhere less than the factorial function that also converges, maybe i'm missing something. But here is my attempt.

I found the first integer in the domain $[1,\infty)$ such that $2^{x} < \Gamma(x+1)$ which I got to be $x=4$. Then I took the integral and split it up.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx = \int_{1}^{4} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx + \int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$$

Now, knowing that $2^x$ is less than $\Gamma(x+1)$ on the interval $[4,\infty)$, we now have that $$\frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}} < \frac {1}{2^{x\epsilon}}$$
and so $$\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx < \int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{2}^{x\epsilon}}dx < \infty$$

And now finally, because $\int_{1}^{4} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$ certainly converges to some finite value, and $\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$ converges to some other finite value by the comparison, then adding them together should show that the entire integral
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx < \infty$$ and converges for any $\epsilon >0$ and then in a sense, so must $\frac{1}{x!}$

Correct?

Comment: This is obvious. Don't write $x!$ for real $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.
Do you mean don't use $x!$ for non- natural number inputs?
If so, then yes, that's why I changed to the Gamma function. I guess my question is actually asking to prove the convergence of the gamma function in that case.

Comment: Recall the Stirling's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Gamma(x+1)$ is a log-convex function by the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem). It follows that:

$$ \forall x\geq 1,\qquad \log\Gamma(x+1)\geq \log\Gamma(1+1)+(x-1)\log\Gamma'(1+1)=(1-\gamma)(x-1) $$
and by exponentiating back, for any $c>0$:
$$ \Gamma(x+1) \geq e^{(1-\gamma)(x-1)},\qquad \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\Gamma(x+1)^c} \leq \frac{1}{c(1-\gamma)}. $$

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: Is that the Euler mascheroni constant?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: exactly. Here it appears since $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$.

Comment: Hmm...I apologize,  but can you explain where exactly $\Gamma'(1+1)$ comes in?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: if $f(x)$ is a convex, $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $$\forall x\geq s,\qquad f(x) \geq f(s)+f'(s)(x-s)$$ is a consequence of convexity. I am just stating that the graph of $f(x)$ lies above the graph of a tangent over the region $x\geq s$.

Comment: So, because $\Gamma(x+1)$ is greater/equal to $e^{x-1}$ then $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}$ is less than \frac{1}{e^{(x-1)}} 

so does integrating both sides prove convergence? Is that what the conclusion there is?

Also, is there an issue with my attempt at it? Like was there a mistake that you could see?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: you are right about my conclusion, bounding $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}$ with $\exp(-C(x-1))$ is enough to prove convergence. Your approach is fine, too, my answer just shows we do not strictly need to split the integration range, but that is a viable option for sure.

Comment: Oh! Okay good.
I'm sorry, I suppose my biggest concern to prove convergence was whether or not we can split the integral up at the inequality bound.

But I suppose this all also follows from the fact that it's log convex.
Thank you!